# Spring cloud GCP com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException access_token not found error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gcp

Spring boot-2.3.10, Spring Cloud Gcp: 1.2.8

I'm trying to access specific image pattern **(/resources/images/specific_folder/****) from GC Storage. For that I wrote the resource handler as shown below:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        log.info("Setting the resource location {}", gcStorageLocation);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/images/specific_folder/**").addResourceLocations("gs:bucket_name/storage/images/specific_folder/").setCachePeriod(3600).resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new GcStorageResolver());
    }
```

GcStorageResolver.java extends AbstractResourceResolver.java

```
@Override
    protected Resource resolveResourceInternal(@Nullable HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations,
            ResourceResolverChain chain) {
        log.info("resolveResourceInternal called for request: {}, requestPath: {}", request.getRequestURL(), requestPath);
        return getResource(requestPath, request, locations);
    }
```

I verified that a valid GoogleStorageResource is being returned along with credential. But somewhere in the spring chain, I'm getting the below error:

> 2021-06-25 15:40:23.366 ERROR 4676 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      175 : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Error parsing token refresh
> response. Expected value access_token not found.] with root cause
>
> java.io.IOException: Error parsing token refresh response. Expected
> value access_token not found.     at
> com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Utils.validateString(OAuth2Utils.java:113)
> ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.22.1.jar:?]   at
> com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:449)
> ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.22.1.jar:?]   at
> com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:157)
> ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.22.1.jar:?]   at
> com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:145)
> ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.22.1.jar:?]   at
> com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:603)
> ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.22.1.jar:?]   at
> com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91)
> ~[google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.22.1.jar:?]   at
> com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$1.initialize(HttpTransportOptions.java:159)
> ~[google-cloud-core-http-1.94.0.jar:1.94.0]   at
> com.google.cloud.http.CensusHttpModule$CensusHttpRequestInitializer.initialize(CensusHttpModule.java:109)
> ~[google-cloud-core-http-1.94.0.jar:1.94.0]   at
> com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:88)
> ~[google-http-client-1.38.0.jar:1.38.0]

Not sure what's going on here. Any pointers?

Comment: Spring Cloud doesn't have a version of 1.2.8. Do you mean spring cloud gcp?

Comment: yes, @spencergibb. Updated the post as well

Comment: The error points to an issue with the refresh token, have you [provided credentials](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_credentials) for authentication?